# What does the OpenCL error "Illegal instruction detected: Only reg allowed as operands in SDWA instructions on GFX9" mean on AMD Radeon VII?

Tags: opencl

I'm getting the very strange error message

```
renamable $vgpr10 = V_OR_B32_sdwa 0, 4, 0, $vgpr5, 0, 6, 0, 6, 4, implicit $exec
error: Illegal instruction detected: Only reg allowed as operands in SDWA instructions on GFX9
4 errors generated. Error: Creating the executable from LLVM IRs failed.
```

when calling this this method in an OpenCL kernel on an AMD Radeon VII GPU, driver `3137.0 (HSA1.1,LC)`:

```c
void colorize_and_connect(uint z0, uint zm, uint y0, uint ym, uint x0, uint xm, uchar* connections, uchar* connections_size_ptr, uchar* index) {
    const uint n = x0+y0+z0;
    if(index[n]==27) {
        const uchar neighbor_indices[6] = {index[xm+y0+z0], index[x0+ym+z0], index[x0+y0+zm],  // -00 0-0 00-
                                           index[xm+ym+z0], index[xm+y0+zm], index[x0+ym+zm]}; // --0 -0- 0--

        ...
    }
}
```

This exact code runs perfectly fine on Nvidia GPUs. On the Radeon VII, when changing the 5th element in `neighbor_indices` from `index[xm+y0+zm]` to `index[x0+y0+z0]`, the error disappears. What the hell is going on here?